# Extract individual years from a time series raster

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, time-series

So there's this [Sea Surface Temperature](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d6efd3aef35f4efebe3dae59da123312) hosted raster layer on ESRI's Living Atlas and I am interested in extracting an individual year's data, for example 1981, from it and export it as a new raster. How can I do this ArcGIS Pro 3.1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a tool to do it in Pro so, making sure that the layer is selected:

1. Go to the `Multidimensional` tab.
2. Click on the `Data Management` drop down menu and select `Subset`.
3. Under `Dimension Definition` select `By Range`.
4. Dimension in this case would be `StdTime`, `Minimum Value` and `Maximum Value` will be the start and end date respectively.

[image]